# Pre-select facet with content from user field

Tags: commerce, search

I have a `City` field in the user profile and I would like to pre-select the faceted search results with the content of that field.

- Latest Commerce kickstart installation, customized.
- The field `City` exists both for the product and user, linked to the same taxonomy dictionary

So, I would like to have the city pre-selected to the user's city whenever the `/product` page is loaded, or a search is executed.
I tried Rules, but found nothing usable.

Thanks in advance!